# How to concatenate all rows into one row of a multi-column DataFrame?

Tags: pandas

In Python,

1. How best to combine all rows of each column in a multi-column DataFrame  into one column,
2. separated by ‘ | ’ separator
3. including null values

   `import pandas as pd
   html = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Norwegian_citizens'
   df = pd.read_html(html, header=0)
   df= df[1]
   df.to_csv('norway.csv)`

[From This:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fd7xu.png)
[To This:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1FH6.png)

Comment: Could you at least add the DataFrame in a form that can be copied into an editor?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need replace missing values if necessary by [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html), convert values to strings with [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) and [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with `join`. Get `Series`, so for one column `DataFrame` add [`to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) with transposing:

```
df = df.fillna(' ').astype(str).apply('|'.join).to_frame().T
print (df)
                      Country Allowed_stay        Visa_requirement
0  Albania|Afganistan|Andorra     30|30|60  visa free| | visa free
```

Or use list comprehension with `DataFrame` constructor:

```
L = ['|'.join(df[x].fillna(' ').astype(str)) for x in df]
df1 = pd.DataFrame([L], columns=df.columns)
print (df1)
                      Country Allowed_stay        Visa_requirement
0  Albania|Afganistan|Andorra     30|30|60  visa free| | visa free
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pandas.DataFrame([
    {'A' : 'x', 'B' : 2, 'C' : None},
    {'A' : None, 'B' : 2, 'C' : 1},
    {'A' : 'y', 'B' : None, 'C' : None},
])

pandas.DataFrame(df.fillna('').apply(lambda x: '|'.join(x.astype(str)), axis = 0)).transpose()
```